# contour map does not show up using ggplot in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wrote this code to try and make a contour map for this data and the contour levels do not show up. I have not used this package in r before so I might just be missing something. There are no errors when running it but it does not show the contour lines. Also, here is the [image of the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZmLy.png). Here is the code: (I didn't know a better way to give you the data I'm using, sorry!)

Data X:

```
ExpectedX <- c(1.48 , 0.727 , 1.65 , 1.29 , 13.9 , 4.14 , 1.02 , 2.95 , 1.62 , 2.53 , 1.22 , 2.35 , 2.13 , 1.86 , 4.01 , 2.36 , -0.133 , 0.958 , 3.14 , 1.62 , 1.46 , 0.927 , 1.04 , 0.481 , 0.298 , -1.62 , 0.53 , 0.986 , -11.4 , 0.336 , 0.36 , 0.564 ,
  -2.87 , 2.14 , 0.875 , -0.543 , 1.54 , 1.3 , 2.13 , 1.12 , 1.72 , 41 , 1.88 , 2.34 , 2.11 , 1.86 , 1.66 , 2.52 , 1.04 , -7.19 , 0.893 , 1.5 , 0.96 , 0.693 , 1.36 , 0.695 , 8.77 , 0.919 , 0.936 , 34.3 , 0.221 , 0.845 , 11.7 , 0.903 , -2.67 , 1.69 , 1.14
  , 0.826 , 1.77 , 3.29 , 3.46 , 0.0399 , 0.215 , 0.782 , 13.1 , 1.61 , 1.53 , 1.76 , 2.73 , 3.12 , 3.5 , 2.15 , 1.89 , 1.98 , 2.52 , 2.02 , 0.337 , 0.981 , 2.19 , 0.735 , -0.539 , 1.19 , -7.18 , 1.1 , 2.49 , 1.36 , -1.76 , 0.761 , 1.29 , -0.815 , 0.446
  , -0.401 , 4.17 , 0.249 , 1.02 , 3.42 , 1.64 , 0.787 , 1.51 , 1.35 , 13.6 , 0.504 , 0.831 , 1.06 , -2.03 , 0.225 , 1.02 , 1.04 , 3.31 , 1.71 , -1.99 , 1.35 , 2.1 , 0.357 , 3 , 1.75 , 0.351 , 0.868 , 2.5 , 0.253 , -0.102 , 1.21 , 0.272 , -0.0949 , -0.721
  , 0.996 , -3.13 , 0.673 , 1.49 , 0.794 , 2.01 , 0.292 , -1.42 , -0.942 , 0.93 , 1.8 , 1.06 , 0.887 , -0.915 , 1.34 , -5.55 , 0.324 , 1.93 , 0.564 , 4.25 , 0.948 , 1.16 , 2.16 , -0.801 , 0.27 , 0.656 , -0.131 , 1.27 , 0.438 , -0.774 , -2.95 , 0.784 , 0.464
  , 0.98 , 58.5 , 0.483 , 0.493 , 0.767 , 1.47 , -5.04 , -0.481 , 1.17 , -0.372 , 0.653 , 2.06 , 1.01 , 0.893 , 0.858 , 0.831 , 0.34 , -2.15 , 1.01 , -44.6 , 1.07 , -1.75 , -0.0984 , 0.502 , 0.574 , 1.2 , -0.747 , -0.0915 , 0.233 , 0.203 , 2.01 , 0.473
  , 0.255 , 6.31 , 0.556 , 4.18 , 0.645 , 1.84 , 1.09 , 0.397 , -0.46 , 0.373 , 0.57 , 1.04 , 0.682 , -4.96 , -1.03 , 0.874 , 0.921 , 0.821 , 0.47 , 0.873 , -1.06 , 2.87 , -0.555 , 0.67 , 1.62 , 2.21 , -4.08 , 1.28 , 0.36 , -0.522 , 0.0548 , 0.996 , 1.06
  , 18.5 , 1.07 , 2.66 , 1.95 , 0.844 , 10.9 , 0.934 , 2.62 , 0.131 , 0.989 , 7.31 , 1.2 , 3.22 , 1.82 , 0.749 , 1.57 , 1.54 , 0.69 , 4.47 , 1.59 , 1.16 , 4.06 , 2.06 , 2.38 , 1.85 , 1.27 , 1.82 , 2.29 , 3.61 , 1.13 , 0.772 , -7.6 , 1.44 , 2.03 , -0.912
  , 1.04 , -4.27 , 0.342 , 0.52 , -0.0915 , 0.503 , 0.37 , 0.0616 , 0.341 , 1.41 , 1.01 , 0.705 , 2.17 , 0.733 , 1.43 , 1.53 , 1.19 , 1.31 , -0.597 , 0.175 , 1.56 , 0.715 , 0.994 , 3.18 , 1.29 , 1.22 , 0.816 , 1.54 , -0.68 , -0.45 , 1.28 , 0.978 , 2.08
  , 1.57 , 2.97 , 1.56 , 1.19 , 1.35 , 1.83 , 2.13 , 2.48 , 2.05 , 3.25 , 4.93 , 2.76 , 1.81 , 1.89 , 1.61 , 2.3 , 2.76 , 2.01 , 1.74 , 1.79 , 1.69 , 1.5 , 3.33 , 1.31 , 2.02 , 1.6 , 1.06 , 1.05 , 1.12 , 2.12 , 2.5 , 1.67 , 1.55 , 2.14 , 1.26 , 1.98 , 0.453
  , 0.278 , 1.1 , 2.31 , 2.45 , 1.27 , 1.05 , -1.58 , 1.11 , 2.61 , 0.276 , 1.26 , 1.39 , 0.905 , 4.67 , 2.72 , 1.05 , 1.44 , 1.94 , 1.68 , 2.11 , 2.47 , 1.06 , 4.49 , 2.62 , 2.41 , 1.51 , 3.03 , 2.05 , 2.18 , 2.11 , 2.27 , 3.11 , 1.85 , 1.67 , 1.44 , 1.07
  , 2.41 , 2.24 , 1.78 , 3.46 , 1.08 , 1.45 , 3.68 , 0.311 , -1.06 , 1.43 , 1.01 , 10 , -1.67 , -0.136 , 0.981 , 0.949 , 8.28 , 0.116 , 0.767 , -4.53 , 1.02 , 1.4 , 0.317 , 1.44 , 1.32 , 1.86 , 1.14 , 1.7 , 2.37 , 1.43 , 2.43 , 1.45 , 1.94 , 3.49 , 1.06
  , 7.04 , 1.62 , 2.89 , 1.03 , 9.94 , 0.466 , 0.58 , -0.344 , 1.05 , 1.64 , 3.75 , 1.01 , 63 , 1.39 , 3 , 2.27 , 1.59 , 1.98 , 1.96 , 2.23 , 1.08 , 0.707 , 0.534 , 0.962 , 2.62 , 1.56 , 1.29 , 3.8 , 1.3 , 1.75 , 1.36 , 4.08 , 1.26 , 3.47 , 1.39 , 3.84
  , 1.74 , 3.05 , 6.44 , 1.92 , 1.56 , 0.332 , 0.981 , 1.52 , 3.81 , -0.176 , 0.874 , -0.218 , 0.27 , 1.07 , -7.06 , 0.124 , 1.02 , -3.88 , 2.95 , 0.896 , -6.17 , 0.986 , 4.59 , 0.831 , 0.749 , 2.82 , 2.1 , 1.51 , 1.39 , 1.2 , 1.41 , -3.12 , 1.3 , 0.606
  , 0.123 , 0.991 , 0.809 , 6.19 , 0.144 , 0.0336 , 1.52 , -2.79 , 1.15 , 10.2 , 2.7 , 2.23 , 1.7 , 2.31 , 1.79 , 2.2 , 2.14 , 2.03 , 1.99 , 3.28 , 1.53 , 1.81 , 2.25 , 2.15 , 1.91 , 1.86 , 2.06 , 3.16 , 1.52 , 1.55 , 2.49 , 2.97 , 6.26 , 1.62 , 1.85 ,
  3.39 , 2.24 , 2.14 , 1.72 , 1.13 , 1.73 , 2.75 , 1.18 , 1.6 , 0.878 , 0.515 , 0.537 , 1.87 , 1.13 , 1.09 , 1.52 , 1.48 , 2.06 , 0.572 , -0.286 , 1.61 , 2.3 , -1.66 , 0.592 , 1.02 , 2.06 , -0.206 , 0.849 , 1.71 , 1.65 , 1.55 , 2.02 , 1.57 , 1.99 , 2.1
  , 1.66 , 1.9 , 1.17 , 0.585 , 0.773 , 2.88 , 2.11 , 1.5 , 2.32 , 0.84 , 1.06 , 2.2 , 4.96 , 0.692 , 0.344 , 2.62 , 1.3 , 1.53 , 1.65 , 1.62 , 2.01 , 2 , 1.95 , 2.56 , 1.53 , 2.5 , 1.55 , 3.12 , 1.25 , 2.28 , 2.17 , 1.63 , 4.04 , 1.51 , 2.43 , 1.48 , 2.16
  , 2.84 , 2.46 , 3.06 , 1.23 , 0.798 , 0.69 , -0.0825 , 0.981 , -0.782 , 0.0378 , 1.39 , -0.83 , 0.272 , 0.175 , 0.0644 , 7.27 , 2.73 , 0.999 , 0.354 , 1.56 , 0.847 , 2.91 , 1.5 , 1.56 , -0.582 , 4.1 , 1.06 , 1.33 , 3.7 , 0.35 , -0.605 , 1.38 , 0.529 ,
  0.406 , 0.0374 , 0.453 , 1.72 , -0.358 , 1.64 , 0.987 , -25.9 , 0.65 , 1.61 , 1.91 , -2.13 , 0.412 , 0.997 , 0.91 , -15.5 , 1.45 , 0.663 , -10.3 , 0.832 , 2.03 , 1.49 , 1.86 , 0.606 , 1.33 , -1.47 , 1.11 , 1.47 , 0.957 , -1.29 , 2.81 , 0.405 , 0.14 ,
  0.403 , 0.388 , 0.933 , -49.6 , 2.08 , 1.26 , 3.21 , 2.66 , 2.11 , 1.92 , 1.76 , 2.33 , 1.87 , 3.21 , 1.81 , 2.07 , 2.1 , 2.93 , 1.77 , 1.89 , 1.9 , 1.96 , 4.76 , 1.36 , 1.95 , 2.33 , 1.95 , 1.96 , 2.42 , 2.74 , 1.24 , 3.04 , 1.08 , 1.13 , 3.81 , 1.18
  , 1.01 , -0.303 , 0.405 , 1.22 , -0.493 , 3.64 , 0.372 , 0.923 , 2.49 , -0.271 , 0.0368 , 0.909 , 1.45 , 0.0491 , 0.988 , -0.958 , 1.01 , 0.844 , 0.0714 , 1.82 , 0.139 , 2.22 , 0.827 , 1.94 , -0.0732 , 2.32 , 1.61 , 1.03 , -2.66 , 2.17 , 1.22 , -0.136
  , 0.833 , 1.8 , 1.19 , -6.45 , 1.2 , 0.825 , 0.716 , 1.82 , 3.83 , -0.177 , 0.956 , -53.5 , 1.02 , 1.63 , 11.1 , 4.19 , 2.5 , 1.76 , 2.13 , 1.97 , 2.05 , -0.346 , 1.47 , 0.246 , 0.726 , 1.16 , 0.62 , 0.598 , 0.532 , 0.691 , -0.178 , 2.15 , 0.479 , 1.12
  , 1.86 , 2.47 , 2.79 , 2.25 , 1.45 , 0.726 , 2.08 , -1.08 , 1.29 , 0.0197 , 0.748 , -0.113 , 0.534 , -2.92 , 1.07 , 22.4 , 2.06 , 1.14 , 1.62 , 0.268 , -17.5 , 2.06 , 1.91 , 2.02 , 2.18 , 1.93 , 1.88 , 2.74 , 2.08 , 2.05 , 1.95 , 1.67 , 1.75 , 2.62 ,
  1.95 , 1.03 , 2.04 , 1.91)
```

DataY:

```
ExpectedY<- c(1.44 , 0.374 , -0.748 , -0.67 , -4.83 , 0.752 , -0.0143 , 3.13 , -0.107 , -0.991 , 0.361 , -1.12 , 1.21 , -1.22 , 0.947 , -0.51 , 1.44 , 1.95 , -5.86 , 0.162 , 0.0217 , -1.42 , -0.145 , 0.128 , -0.837 , 1.39 , 0.126 , -0.0623 , -1.35 , -6.75
  , 0.309 , -0.638 , 1.47 , -0.492 , 0.0901 , 2.92 , 0.226 , 0.157 , 0.224 , 0.23 , -0.896 , 32.4 , -0.314 , 0.0528 , 0.0909 , -0.0391 , -0.0927 , 0.506 , -0.0622 , -10.7 , 0.332 , -0.201 , -0.0691 , 0.08 , -4.62 , -0.405 , -15.9 , -0.0998 , 0.275 , -2.79
  , 0.0604 , -0.0277 , 4.92 , -0.0183 , 2.73 , 0.315 , -0.00641 , 0.774 , -0.955 , -0.996 , -3.86 , -0.31 , -0.628 , -0.606 , -1.17 , 0.248 , -0.137 , 0.0913 , 0.531 , -0.17 , 0.306 , 0.175 , 0.32 , 0.126 , 0.105 , 0.103 , 0.981 , 0.124 , -0.828 , -2.09
  , -1.81 , -0.00192 , 0.28 , -0.0293 , 0.187 , 0.0384 , -3.73 , -0.697 , -0.343 , 0.177 , 0.0351 , 0.698 , -3.67 , 0.24 , 0.0351 , 3.35 , -1.68 , -0.135 , -1.68 , -0.0622 , 10.4 , -1.06 , -0.81 , 0.303 , 0.0311 , 0.451 , 0.0633 , 1.22 , 1.59 , 0.596 ,
  2.02 , -0.288 , -0.0111 , 0.295 , 2.74 , -0.166 , -0.473 , -0.442 , 0.681 , -2.99 , 0.112 , -0.318 , -0.158 , -0.18 , 0.175 , -0.248 , -7.12 , 0.0926 , 0.882 , -0.251 , 0.799 , 0.0783 , -0.24 , -1.31 , -0.0327 , -2.7 , -2.02 , 0.352 , -1.75 , -0.0351
  , -4.6 , 0.198 , 0.171 , -0.00135 , 0.0796 , 0.41 , 1.04 , -0.848 , -1.54 , 0.205 , -0.324 , 0.889 , 0.102 , 0.158 , 0.741 , 0.0866 , 0.563 , 1.91 , -0.00651 , -32 , 0.0379 , 0.221 , 0.0904 , -0.396 , -15.8 , -0.301 , -0.272 , -2.79 , 0.0397 , 0.178 ,
  0.37 , -3.31 , 0.0173 , 1.1 , -1.78 , 0.223 , 0.0695 , 5.52 , -0.0721 , -3.16 , -0.424 , -0.313 , -0.592 , 0.125 , -0.853 , 1.84 , -0.28 , 0.513 , -0.0993 , -0.104 , -0.0177 , 0.989 , -0.402 , -1.91 , -0.169 , -0.855 , -0.207 , 4.86 , 0.0148 , 0.0629
  , 0.265 , -0.166 , -1.46 , -6.31 , 0.563 , 0.308 , -0.438 , -1.33 , 0.454 , 0.231 , 1.69 , 1.57 , -0.867 , 0.138 , 0.116 , -0.0499 , -0.525 , -0.0467 , 0.985 , -2.1 , -0.24 , 0.133 , -0.219 , -9.2 , -0.00757 , -2.18 , 0.244 , 0.145 , 9.49 , -0.317 , -4.67
  , -0.828 , 0.0693 , 5.29 , -0.37 , 0.27 , 0.704 , -0.99 , 0.462 , 0.46 , -0.269 , 2.6 , 0.842 , 0.079 , 1.12 , -0.168 , 0.922 , -0.312 , -0.335 , 0.0989 , -0.457 , -0.904 , 0.476 , -0.0584 , -0.638 , -0.281 , -0.548 , 1.85 , -0.171 , -1.96 , 0.945 , 0.652
  , -0.00809 , 0.0933 , -0.0294 , 0.939 , -1.63 , 2.08 , 0.155 , -1.11 , -1.09 , 1.71 , -0.178 , -0.0578 , -6.65 , 0.136 , 0.514 , -1.3 , 0.164 , -1.56 , 0.296 , 1.41 , -0.835 , 0.514 , -0.847 , -0.0515 , 2.22 , -0.616 , 0.645 , 0.0859 , -7.63 , -0.425
  , 2.77 , -0.35 , 1.37 , -0.978 , -0.00182 , 0.158 , 0.527 , -0.381 , 0.811 , -0.722 , -0.231 , -0.0335 , 0.385 , -0.099 , 0.327 , -0.202 , 0.0892 , 0.123 , -0.0181 , -0.342 , -0.0385 , 1.39 , 0.156 , 0.0177 , 0.358 , -0.88 , 2.07 , -0.221 , 0.249 , 0.13
  , -1.02 , 1.37 , 0.745 , -0.093 , -0.389 , -2.58 , 0.629 , -0.112 , 0.735 , -1.51 , -1.18 , -0.544 , -1.73 , -0.244 , -3.36 , 0.656 , -0.552 , 0.137 , -0.335 , 1.39 , 1.8 , 0.322 , -1.25 , -0.193 , 0.103 , 0.891 , -1.53 , 0.149 , -0.0366 , -0.677 , -0.301
  , -0.159 , 1.26 , 0.079 , -1.01 , 0.77 , -0.495 , 0.615 , -0.336 , 0.0137 , -0.962 , 0.165 , -0.775 , -0.666 , 0.306 , -0.365 , -0.0329 , -0.229 , 4.36 , 0.0279 , -0.271 , -0.673 , 0.0229 , -16.6 , 1.78 , -0.67 , -0.00962 , 1.59 , 9.59 , 0.66 , 0.139
  , 8.56 , 0.0884 , 2.42 , 1.16 , -0.00455 , 3.25 , -0.391 , -0.072 , 5.92 , -0.656 , -0.141 , -0.433 , 0.0939 , 0.0764 , 0.384 , 0.11 , -3.31 , -0.654 , 0.983 , 0.0122 , 1.99 , -1.46 , -0.0288 , -2.13 , 0.126 , -3.13 , 0.362 , 0.00988 , -25.2 , 0.0842
  , -0.947 , 0.288 , 0.0856 , -0.0167 , -0.285 , 0.116 , 0.169 , -2.05 , 1 , -3.3 , 0.652 , 0.109 , 0.0584 , -1.87 , -0.11 , 0.373 , 0.48 , -1.42 , -0.622 , 3.56 , -0.319 , 0.276 , 0.204 , -0.00648 , -0.572 , 0.025 , 0.0578 , 0.524 , -1.26 , -0.0596 , -1.85
  , 0.532 , 0.112 , 4.8 , 3.67 , -0.0399 , -1.51 , -0.264 , -0.0403 , 4.87 , -0.484 , -0.0546 , 3.07 , -0.407 , -12.8 , 0.674 , -0.336 , 3.37 , 0.319 , 0.163 , -0.262 , -0.47 , -0.19 , 4.74 , -0.0989 , -0.249 , 0.0262 , -0.439 , 0.304 , -14.7 , -0.0445
  , 0.21 , 0.685 , -0.563 , 0.355 , 3.42 , 0.89 , -0.25 , -0.54 , -0.0949 , -0.0493 , 0.0272 , -0.00478 , 0.244 , 0.169 , 0.142 , 0.193 , -0.21 , -0.0326 , 0.143 , 0.11 , -0.0657 , -0.14 , 0.0944 , -0.0886 , 0.37 , -1.4 , 2.79 , -1.69 , 0.149 , -0.028 ,
  0.647 , 0.0251 , -0.0247 , 0.361 , 0.087 , -0.35 , -3.19 , 0.0931 , 1.72 , -1.71 , 0.033 , -0.361 , -0.64 , -0.528 , 0.888 , -0.848 , 1.04 , 0.382 , -0.265 , 1.03 , -0.255 , 0.0678 , 5.05 , -0.313 , 0.303 , -0.888 , -2.72 , 0.279 , -0.714 , 0.513 , -1.17
  , 3 , -0.15 , -0.0344 , -0.165 , 0.948 , -1.3 , 0.162 , -6.62 , 0.571 , -3.5 , 0.379 , 0.149 , -0.141 , 0.255 , -0.47 , -0.872 , -1.89 , 0.0989 , -0.384 , -0.0669 , 0.348 , -0.714 , 0.816 , 0.164 , -0.47 , -0.851 , 0.437 , -0.253 , 0.221 , -0.918 , 0.361
  , -1.14 , 0.00209 , 0.358 , -0.958 , 0.197 , -0.518 , 0.403 , -0.857 , 0.166 , -0.557 , 0.345 , -0.558 , 0.0195 , 0.261 , -0.309 , 0.0416 , 0.684 , -0.189 , -7.63 , -0.752 , 0.342 , 0.0683 , 0.106 , -0.184 , -0.504 , 4.32 , 0.83 , -0.03 , 1.43 , 2.95
  , 0.024 , -1.06 , 1.69 , -0.151 , 1.47 , -12.9 , -0.0379 , 1.21 , -4.32 , -0.092 , -0.352 , -0.316 , 1.09 , -0.0698 , 0.118 , -0.0438 , 0.501 , -0.182 , -0.0623 , -0.16 , -15.3 , -0.168 , -0.233 , -0.166 , 0.361 , -0.157 , -0.14 , -0.0737 , 16.1 , 0.0295
  , 0.568 , -3.2 , -0.00719 , -1.46 , -0.624 , -1.04 , -0.668 , 0.722 , -0.564 , -0.0307 , 2.52 , 0.526 , -3.45 , -0.0143 , 0.539 , 0.174 , -0.0826 , 0.256 , 0.544 , -33.3 , -0.499 , -0.119 , 0.659 , 1.42 , -0.0612 , 0.0583 , -0.0968 , 0.341 , -0.275 ,
  0.145 , -0.135 , -0.0111 , 0.355 , 0.808 , 0.0755 , 0.154 , -0.0828 , 0.154 , -0.155 , -0.238 , 0.0326 , 0.362 , -0.546 , -0.128 , 0.00245 , 0.47 , 0.0641 , 0.576 , -0.105 , 0.551 , 0.0963 , 1.64 , 0.328 , -0.519 , 0.403 , 0.181 , 0.692 , 0.39 , 0.0169
  , 0.186 , 4.1 , -0.112 , -0.457 , -0.578 , 2.54 , 0.105 , 0.0865 , -2.49 , -0.251 , 0.311 , 0.786 , 0.848 , 1.39 , 7.33 , -0.428 , 0.47 , -1.33 , 1.04 , -0.826 , -0.0182 , 9.93 , 0.0764 , 0.265 , -0.473 , -0.812 , -2.04 , 0.176 , -5.63 , -0.166 , 0.398
  , -3.78 , 0.436 , 0.163 , -0.0193 , 0.07 , 130 , -0.0355 , 0.929 , -1.4 , 0.261 , 0.117 , 0.0322 , -0.159 , -0.0375 , 0.0316 , 0.849 , -3.54 , -0.14 , 0.0608 , -1.63 , -0.47 , -5.11 , -0.183 , 0.258 , 0.88 , 1.75 , 0.483 , -0.381 , -0.991 , -0.0788 ,
  1.39 , -0.414 , 0.19 , -0.374 , 0.174 , -0.951 , 0.498 , 0.277 , -0.0598 , 0.101 , 0.0722 , -2.14 , -0.161 , 72.7 , -0.248 , 0.022 , 0.907 , 0.427 , 17.2 , -0.143 , 0.155 , -0.111 , -0.122 , 0.0513 , -0.24 , 0.00188 , 0.0783 , 0.161 , -0.0755 , -0.071
  , -0.163 , 0.437 , 0.15 , -0.067 , -0.0784 , -0.123)
```

Code:

```
library(MASS)
library(ggplot2)
differentPlotData <- cbind(ExpectedX,ExpectedY)
commonTheme = list(labs(color="Density",fill="Density",
                        x="Expected X Position",
                        y="Expected Y Position"),
                   theme_bw(),
                   theme(legend.position=c(0,1),
                         legend.justification=c(-7,1.1)))
ggplot(data=differentPlotData,aes(ExpectedX,ExpectedY)) + 
  stat_density2d(aes fill=..level..,alpha=..level..),geom='polygon',colour='gray60') + 
  scale_fill_continuous(low="green",high="red") +
  geom_smooth(method=lm,linetype=2,colour="red",se=F) + 
  guides(alpha="none") +
  geom_point(shape = "o", alpha = 0.2) + commonTheme
```

Comment: In the future just use code blocks by indenting by 4 spaces. Snippets are used for HTML, CSS, and Javascript example. :)

Comment: I think your `geom_point` extent makes your x and y limits too large to see your polygons. Try adding `coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-3, 3), ylim = c(-3, 3))` to your ggplot object. When I do that I can see your `stat_density2d()` polygons- are those what you mean by adding contour lines?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean. Is there any way I can change the density value so it makes the polygons bigger?

Comment: You could try playing around with the number of bins- try `bin = 50` or so. That said, your data is high density in that one spot, not sure that it helps all that much.